# How to fill column based on condition taking other columns into account?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

to fill an empty column of a dataframe based on a condition taking another column into account, i have found following solution, which works fine, but is somehow a little bit ugly. does anybody know a more elegant way to solve this?

```
base::set.seed(123)
test_df <- base::data.frame(vec1 = base::sample(base::seq(1, 100, 1), 50), vec2 = base::seq(1, 50, 1), vec3 = NA)

for (a in 1:base::nrow(test_df)){
  spc_test_df <- test_df[a, ]
  # select the specific row of the dataframe
  if(spc_test_df$vec1 <= 25 | spc_test_df$vec1 >= 75){
    # evaluate whether the deviation is below/above the threshold
    spc_test_df$vec3 <- 1
    # if so, write TRUE
  } else {
    spc_test_df$vec3 <- 0
    # if not so, write FALSE
  }
  test_df[a, ] <- spc_test_df
  # write the specific row back to the dataframe
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `ifelse` function? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse

Comment: Your condition is a bit odd: `spc_test_df$vec1 <= 25 | spc_test_df$vec1 >= 25` essentially selects all cases; consequently everything is set to `1`.

Comment: (1) Your calcs here should be vectorized, don't use a `for` loop. (2) Don't use `|` in an `if` conditional unless it is summarized (e.g., `any`, `all`), instead use `||` (rationale includes short-circuiting). (3) Ditto the reference to `ifelse`, perhaps something like `test_df$vec3 <- ifelse(test_df$vec1 <= 25, 1, 0)` or, since the yes/no values are 1 and 0, preferably `test_df$vec3 <- +(test_df$vec1 <= 25)` (and whatever you really mean for your logic second-half, `. <= 25 | . >= 25` is certainly confusing).

Comment: sorry, i edited the question. thanks a lot for your answers so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a for-loop as you can use vectorized solutions in this case. Three options on how to solve this problem:

```
# option 1
test_df$vec3 <- +(test_df$vec1 <= 25 | test_df$vec1 >= 75)

# option 2
test_df$vec3 <- as.integer(test_df$vec1 <= 25 | test_df$vec1 >= 75)

# option 3
test_df$vec3 <- ifelse(test_df$vec1 <= 25 | test_df$vec1 >= 75, 1, 0)
```

which in all cases gives:

```
   vec1 vec2 vec3
1     5    1    1
2     6    2    1
3    61    3    0
4    20    4    1

....

47    3   47    1
48   55   48    0
49   44   49    0
50   97   50    1
```

(only first and last four rows presentend)